# Why are Embeddings in PyTorch implemented as Sparse Layers?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

[Embedding](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#embedding) Layers in PyTorch are listed under "Sparse Layers" with the limitation:

> Keep in mind that only a limited number of optimizers support sparse gradients: currently it’s optim.SGD (cuda and cpu), and optim.Adagrad (cpu)

What is the reason for this? For example in Keras I can train an architecture with an Embedding Layer using any optimizer.

Comment: It is better to ask such question on [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/).

Comment: Good idea! So good in fact that I was immediately able to answer my question after searching the PyTorch forums!

Comment: You answer did not really answer you question, i.e., why embedding is implemented as sparse layer.

Comment: Good point. I'll see if I can figure it out and make an update to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon closer inspection sparse gradients on Embeddings are optional and can be turned on or off with the `sparse` parameter:

> class torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings, embedding_dim, padding_idx=None, max_norm=None, norm_type=2, scale_grad_by_freq=False, **sparse=False**)

Where:

> sparse (boolean, optional) – if True, gradient w.r.t. weight matrix
>   will be a sparse tensor. See Notes for more details regarding sparse
>   gradients.

And the "Notes" mentioned are what I quoted in the question about a limited number of optimizers being supported for sparse gradients.

**Update:**

It is theoretically possible but technically difficult to implement some optimization methods on sparse gradients. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1285) in the PyTorch repo to add support for all optimizers.

Regarding the original question, I believe Embeddings can be treated as sparse because it is possible to operate on the input indices directly rather than converting them to one-hot encodings for input into a dense layer. This is explained in [@Maxim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712995/maxim) answer to my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869811/58866).