# Is tensorflow embedding_lookup differentiable?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, word-embedding, sequence-to-sequence

Some of the tutorials I came across, described using a randomly initialized embedding matrix and then using the `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` function to obtain the embeddings for the integer sequences. I am under the impression that since the `embedding_matrix` is obtained through `tf.get_variable`, the optimizer would add appropriate **ops** for updating it.

What I don't understand is how backpropagation happens through the lookup function which seems to be hard rather than being soft. What is the gradient of the this operation wrt. one of it's input ids?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Embedding matrix lookup is mathematically equivalent to dot product with the one-hot encoded matrix (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47868265/712995)), which is a smooth linear operation.

For example, here's a lookup at the index `3`:

[image: look-up]

Here's the formula for the gradient:

[image: gradient]

... where left-hand side is the derivative of negative log-likelihood (i.e., the objective function), `x` are the input words, `W` is the embedding matrix and `delta` is the error signal.

[`tf.nn.embedding_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) is optimized so that no one-hot encoding conversion happens, but the backprop is working according to the same formula.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Cheers!

Comment: @Maxim Could you please post the source of the gradient calculation equation which you posted here ?

Comment: I like this explanation better.  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33041/backpropgating-error-to-emedding-matrix